# How can I convert these categorial covariates back to being continuous covariates under specific conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, cox-regression, rms

Please, find my data sample `e` below.

**Problem:** continuous covariates are being treated as categorial covariates in Cox Regression

**Question:** I need to **(1)** keep all `.0` on all integers but in such a way that **(2)** `e$Ki67` and `e$age` remain continuous in my Cox Regression. How can this be done?

I recently received great [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60697611/how-can-i-specifically-add-0-to-integers-in-a-column-containing-both-integers-a/60697620?noredirect=1#comment107390091_60697620) here on SO, as I wanted to add `.0` to all integers in a column containing both integers and decimals.

The solution was

```
e$Ki67 <- sprintf("%0.1f", as.numeric(as.character(e$Ki67)))
e$age <- sprintf("%0.1f", as.numeric(as.character(e$age)))
```

So that

```
> head(e)
     rfs Ki67 WHO simpson  age sex rad.dose recurrence dead     os
1  25.33  0.6   1       1 43.0   1        0          1    0 214.67
2 207.93  3.3   2       2 76.0   1        0          0    1 207.93
3  80.00  1.0   2       1 79.0   1        0          0    1  80.00
4  47.77  0.6   1       3 84.0   1        0          1    1  52.67
5 193.25  0.6   1       1 62.0   1        0          0    1 193.25
6   6.08  3.7   2       3 71.0   1        0          1    1  65.54
```

However, when running my Cox Regression, I receive this error:

> In fitter(X, Y, strata = Strata, offset = offset, weights = weights,  :
>   Ran out of iterations and did not converge

It seems that `cph` from the `rms`-package now consider `e$Ki67` and `e$age` categorial covariates, but they are in fact continuous covariates:

```
> summary(a)
             Effects              Response : Surv(rfs, recurrence) 

 Factor          Low High  Diff. Effect      S.E.       Lower 0.95  Upper 0.95 
 rad.dose         0  53.24 53.24 -8.7557e+00 1.0340e+01 -2.9021e+01  1.1510e+01
  Hazard Ratio    0  53.24 53.24  1.5757e-04         NA  2.4899e-13  9.9714e+04
 Ki67 - 0.2:0.5   4   1.00    NA -3.4399e+01 1.0790e+00 -3.6514e+01 -3.2284e+01
  Hazard Ratio    4   1.00    NA  1.1498e-15         NA  1.3873e-16  9.5298e-15
 Ki67 - 0.3:0.5   4   2.00    NA -2.7546e+01 1.6863e+01 -6.0596e+01  5.5041e+00
  Hazard Ratio    4   2.00    NA  1.0887e-12         NA  4.8242e-27  2.4569e+02
 Ki67 - 0.4:0.5   4   3.00    NA  5.8874e+00 7.6362e+00 -9.0793e+00  2.0854e+01
  Hazard Ratio    4   3.00    NA  3.6046e+02         NA  1.1400e-04  1.1398e+09
 Ki67 - 0.6:0.5   4   5.00    NA  2.8224e-02 1.4846e+00 -2.8816e+00  2.9380e+00
  Hazard Ratio    4   5.00    NA  1.0286e+00         NA  5.6047e-02  1.8878e+01
 Ki67 - 0.7:0.5   4   6.00    NA  9.0075e+00 2.5211e+00  4.0662e+00  1.3949e+01
  Hazard Ratio    4   6.00    NA  8.1643e+03         NA  5.8336e+01  1.1426e+06
 Ki67 - 0.8:0.5   4   7.00    NA -3.4891e-01 3.0083e+00 -6.2451e+00  5.5473e+00
  Hazard Ratio    4   7.00    NA  7.0545e-01         NA  1.9399e-03  2.5654e+02
```

So; I need to **(1)** keep all `.0` on all integers but in such a way that **(2)** `e$Ki67` and `e$age` remain continuous in my Cox Regression.

I have used the following script:

```
e$Ki67 <- sprintf("%0.1f", as.numeric(as.character(e$Ki67)))
e$age <- sprintf("%0.1f", as.numeric(as.character(e$age)))

library(rms)
d <- datadist(e)
options(datadist="d")

e$WHO <- as.factor(e$WHO)
e$simpson <- as.factor(e$simpson)
e$sex <- as.factor(e$sex)

a <- cph(Surv(rfs,recurrence)~Ki67+simpson+WHO+age+sex+rad.dose,data=e,surv=TRUE,x=TRUE,y=TRUE)
```

With the following data `e`:

```
e <- structure(list(rfs = c(25.33, 207.93, 80, 47.77, 193.25, 6.08, 
0.69, 174.85, 30.75, 27.27, 162.27, 204.98, 122.81, 20.53, 22.28, 
197.65, 94.23, 195.94, 92.19, 6.93, 193.38, 14.09, 152.38, 49.15, 
190.46, 50.56, 66.76, 188.58, 188.42, 78.65, 125.77, 176.59, 
185.69, 185.23, 184.71, 184.31, 183.59, 181.49, 96.53, 180.63, 
30.16, 65.71, 179.48, 122.61, 177.35, 176.66, 0.13, 67.15, 175.31, 
86.74, 174.65, 169.53, 169.23, 41.99, 168.77, 167.69, 56.71, 
163.84, 163.81, 162.69, 162.63, 162.37, 119.59, 160.1, 159.47, 
12.42, 155.56, 155.47, 155.27, 154.87, 154.61, 128.43, 56.51, 
150.67, 50.79, 47.93, 83.58, 146.1, 144.69, 159.31, 140.58, 136.64, 
135.52, 88.41, 134.11, 134.18, 133.49, 131.81, 77.04, 130.6, 
63.87, 62.98, 88.51, 123.5, 122.45, 121.72, 121.69, 120.57, 1.54, 
114.79), Ki67 = c("0.6", "3.3", "1.0", "0.6", "0.6", "3.7", "1.4", 
"1.1", "1.8", "1.6", "0.7", "0.5", "0.3", "1.7", "0.5", "1.2", 
"4.1", "0.6", "1.4", "1.3", "1.8", "2.6", "0.7", "0.8", "1.0", 
"0.7", "0.7", "2.1", "1.3", "2.7", "1.3", "0.8", "1.1", "1.8", 
"1.8", "0.4", "0.9", "6.4", "1.7", "1.5", "0.6", "2.7", "0.4", 
"1.5", "1.4", "1.8", "2.3", "0.7", "2.4", "1.2", "0.6", "0.8", 
"3.0", "4.0", "0.5", "1.2", "5.1", "1.5", "0.6", "1.2", "1.7", 
"0.7", "1.4", "2.7", "1.1", "0.9", "0.5", "0.7", "0.9", "0.4", 
"0.8", "0.8", "0.5", "0.9", "0.5", "1.2", "1.4", "2.5", "2.7", 
"4.2", "0.8", "0.5", "1.7", "1.2", "1.6", "0.5", "2.6", "2.0", 
"3.9", "0.6", "0.2", "0.5", "0.8", "0.5", "0.5", "0.6", "1.4", 
"0.9", "1.0", "1.8"), WHO = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), simpson = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), age = c("43.0", 
"76.0", "79.0", "84.0", "62.0", "71.0", "75.0", "69.0", "53.0", 
"70.0", "56.0", "45.0", "77.0", "72.0", "56.0", "59.0", "84.0", 
"72.0", "83.0", "80.0", "49.0", "50.0", "68.0", "49.0", "46.0", 
"50.0", "73.0", "51.0", "45.0", "42.0", "73.0", "56.0", "63.0", 
"30.0", "67.0", "56.0", "58.0", "72.0", "51.0", "49.0", "68.0", 
"65.0", "60.0", "64.0", "52.0", "65.0", "76.0", "78.0", "74.0", 
"39.0", "30.0", "66.0", "58.0", "49.0", "67.0", "53.0", "69.0", 
"41.0", "42.0", "66.0", "57.0", "52.0", "25.0", "64.0", "48.0", 
"51.0", "47.0", "46.0", "44.0", "68.0", "41.0", "76.0", "65.0", 
"60.0", "46.0", "54.0", "66.0", "42.0", "46.0", "83.0", "72.0", 
"54.0", "51.0", "77.0", "58.0", "49.0", "52.0", "66.0", "50.0", 
"32.0", "71.0", "45.0", "68.0", "55.0", "55.0", "44.0", "27.0", 
"61.0", "76.0", "47.0"), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), rad.dose = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
5.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.4, 0, 0, 53.24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), recurrence = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), dead = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), os = c(214.67, 207.93, 80, 52.67, 
193.25, 65.54, 0.69, 174.85, 206.29, 27.27, 162.27, 204.98, 122.81, 
49.94, 22.28, 197.65, 94.23, 195.94, 92.19, 6.93, 193.38, 18.37, 
152.38, 49.15, 190.46, 144.07, 66.76, 188.58, 188.42, 78.65, 
125.77, 176.59, 185.69, 185.23, 184.71, 184.31, 183.59, 181.49, 
96.53, 180.63, 112.92, 179.88, 179.48, 122.61, 177.35, 176.66, 
0.13, 67.15, 175.31, 174.82, 174.65, 169.53, 169.23, 168.8, 168.77, 
167.69, 167.29, 163.84, 163.81, 162.69, 162.63, 162.37, 162.2, 
160.1, 159.47, 157.4, 155.56, 155.47, 155.27, 154.87, 154.61, 
128.43, 56.51, 150.67, 148.73, 147.98, 146.83, 146.1, 144.69, 
159.31, 140.58, 136.64, 135.52, 125.77, 134.11, 134.18, 133.49, 
131.81, 77.04, 130.6, 63.87, 126.78, 88.51, 123.5, 122.45, 121.72, 
121.69, 120.57, 1.54, 114.79)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What's the rationale behind `.00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few issues but the main one is that the variables you are interested in are character variables:

```
str(e)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ rfs       : num  25.3 207.9 80 47.8 193.2 ...
 $ Ki67      : chr  "0.6" "3.3" "1.0" "0.6" ...
 $ WHO       : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ simpson   : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 1 3 1 3 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ age       : chr  "43.0" "76.0" "79.0" "84.0" ...
 $ sex       : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ rad.dose  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ recurrence: int  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ dead      : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ os        : num  214.7 207.9 80 52.7 193.2 ...
```

Just change them to numeric so that `cph` recognizes them as such:

```
e$Ki67 <- as.numeric(e$Ki67)
e$age <- as.numeric(e$Ki67)
```

you can't have a variable as continuous but also character. I don't see the point of using `sprintf` here. If you want it for presentation purposes you could create a second copy of the variables and then use them for tables etc but i dont think that necessary, this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347734/printing-blanks-instead-of-nas-when-using-formattable-in-r) for presenting data.

The bigger issue is the model still wont run but I think thats because you are overfitting here with a small sample, it may work on your full dataset.